# Django Queryset for mysql replace

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, mysql-8.0

Is there any `queryset` equivalent in django for the following query.

```
UPDATE table
SET field = REPLACE(field, 'string', 'anothervalue')
WHERE field LIKE '%string%';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.,  we need to use `Replace` DB functions. looks like below.

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Replace  

Model.objects.update(field=Replace(
    'field', Value('string'), Value('anothervalue')
))
```

for more info [official docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#replace)

Answer (score 0):

Check Django docs for [contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#contains) and [icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)

```
lst = Model.objects.filter(field__icontains="string")
for i in lst: i.field = 'anothervalue'; i.save()
```

Comment: thanks for the help., i updated my answer which is more efficient and prevent race conditions.